# Como puedo evitar que descarguen mis archivos pdf y solo lo puedan ver en mi biblioteca web en reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pdf, go

Yo estoy creando una pagina web que es un biblioteca web que muestra archivos pdf, Lo he programado en **Reactjs y con un api en golang y una base de datos en mysql**. Pero mi pregunta es, **como protejo mis archivos para que nadie pueda descargar y solo puedan ver**. Porque actualmente mis archivos están dentro del codigo de reactjs. Y no quiero que alguien entre al código fuente y busque las carpeta donde estan y los descarguen. **Y no se que hacer? Donde se guardan esas carpetas con los archivos para que estén protegidas y solo mi pagina pueda acceder para mostrarlos y no descargarlos** o se se ve en el hosting?
Les agradecería mucho si me dan una idea para hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.